# Application on OSX cannot spawn more than 2048 threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, macos, rust

I have a Rust application on on OSX firing up a large amount of threads as can be seen in the code below, however, after looking at how many max threads my version of OSX is allowed to create via the `sysctl kern.num_taskthreads` command, I can see that it is `kern.num_taskthreads: 2048` which explains why I can't spin up over 2048 threads.

How do I go about getting past this hard limit?

```
let threads = 300000;
let requests = 1;

for _x in 0..threads {
    println!("{}", _x);
    let request_clone = request.clone();

    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        for _y in 0..requests {
            request_clone.lock().unwrap().push((request::Request::new(request::Request::create_request())));
        }
    });

    child_threads.push(handle);
}
```

Comment: Any details on why you want to create so many threads? That seems excessive.

Comment: Load testing application, concurrent users hitting a HTTP resource at once.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to create a smaller "pool" of threads and then iterate over them? You could juggle many connections per thread (hundreds?)

Comment: Maybe on OS X you could use Grand Central Dispatch instead of threads.  `dispatch_async` to one of the standard concurrent global queues.

Comment: @jocull could you give an example of that?

Comment: @JacobClark Unfortunately I'm not fluent enough in Rust yet :( Just hoping to provide some direction!

Comment: If you are using any HTTP libraries, it might help to include a link to them.

Comment: https://github.com/hyperium/hyper

Comment: "which explains why I can't spin up over 2048 threads" - "How do I go about getting past this hard limit" — You answered it yourself: **you can't**. You should reword your question to avoid the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you really want to know how to create more simultaneous HTTP requests than you can create threads.

Comment: For asynchronous HTTP processing I'm using cURL usually. It's a good quality and well-maintained project. I haven't reached the stage yet where I'll need to use it from Rust, though, so I can't boast some Rust code. The existing Rust driver https://github.com/carllerche/curl-rust only works with "easy" handlers and thus isn't sufficient for the job.

Answer (score 7):

Before starting, I'd encourage you to read about the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html). When you get into this scale, there's a lot more things you need to keep in mind.

That being said, I'd suggest looking at [mio](https://github.com/carllerche/mio)...

> a lightweight IO library for Rust with a focus on adding as little overhead as possible over the OS abstractions.

Specifically, mio provides an *event loop*, which allows you to handle a large number of connections without spawning threads. Unfortunately, I don't know of a HTTP library that currently supports mio. You could create one and be a hero to the Rust community!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how helpful this will be, but I was trying to create a small pool of threads that will create connections and then send them over to an event loop via a channel for reading.

I'm sure this code is probably pretty bad, but here it is anyways for examples. It uses the Hyper library, like you mentioned.

```rust
extern crate hyper;

use std::io::Read;
use std::thread;
use std::thread::{JoinHandle};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

use hyper::Client;
use hyper::client::Response;
use hyper::header::Connection;

const TARGET: i32 = 100;
const THREADS: i32 = 10;

struct ResponseWithString {
    index: i32,
    response: Response,
    data: Vec<u8>,
    complete: bool
}

fn main() {
    // Create a client.
    let url: &'static str = "http://www.gooogle.com/";

    let mut threads = Vec::<JoinHandle<()>>::with_capacity((TARGET * 2) as usize);
    let conn_count = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<ResponseWithString>();

    for _ in 0..THREADS {
        // Move var references into thread context
        let conn_count = conn_count.clone();
        let tx = tx.clone();

        let t = thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
                let idx: i32;
                {
                    // Lock, increment, and release
                    let mut count = conn_count.lock().unwrap();
                    *count += 1;
                    idx = *count;
                }
                if idx > TARGET {
                    break;
                }

                let mut client = Client::new();

                // Creating an outgoing request.
                println!("Creating connection {}...", idx);
                let res = client.get(url)                       // Get URL...
                                .header(Connection::close())    // Set headers...
                                .send().unwrap();               // Fire!

                println!("Pushing response {}...", idx);
                tx.send(ResponseWithString {
                    index: idx,
                    response: res,
                    data: Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(1024),
                    complete: false
                }).unwrap();
            }
        });
        threads.push(t);
    }

    let mut responses = Vec::<ResponseWithString>::with_capacity(TARGET as usize);
    let mut buf: [u8; 1024] = [0; 1024];
    let mut completed_count = 0;
    loop {
        if completed_count >= TARGET {
            break; // No more work!
        }

        match rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(r) => {
                println!("Incoming response! {}", r.index);
                responses.push(r)
            },
            _ => { }
        }

        for r in &mut responses {
            if r.complete {
                continue;
            }

            // Read the Response.
            let res = &mut r.response;
            let data = &mut r.data;
            let idx = &r.index;

            match res.read(&mut buf) {
                Ok(i) => {
                        if i == 0 {
                            println!("No more data! {}", idx);
                            r.complete = true;
                            completed_count += 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            println!("Got data! {} => {}", idx, i);
                            for x in 0..i {
                                data.push(buf[x]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                Err(e) => {
                    panic!("Oh no! {} {}", idx, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I must be missing a piece, but how does this have more than #`THREADS` concurrent connections?

Comment: There is a mutex tracking the number of opened connections, used inside a loop in each thread. `THREADS` is the number of threads working to open connections, while `TARGET` is the number of connections it's trying to open. It's a weak example, but I wanted to show another way of handling the connections instead of one-per-thread.

Comment: Ah, I see. So each thread is responsible for opening new connections, but something else is responsible for closing them, which means more connections can be open than the thread count!

Comment: Correct! They're passed into a channel that reads from them in a loop. This could be expanded to include threads as well.

Comment: Have you been able to measure from the "other side" and determine how many concurrent connections this actually enables?

Comment: @Shepmaster I have not -- it was only an experiment to see if I could juggle lots of connections with a small number of concrete threads.